# Docker build: runnable is in parent folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have multiple Dockerfiles in a different folder but the source for all the dockers is the same.

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.5-stretch

COPY my.zip /home/my.zip

RUN unzip /home/target.zip -d /home/ && rm -f /home/target.zip

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/home/my/{a.jar, b.jar, ...}"
```

Either one of the jar will be used in one Docker file.
I have a python script which runs all the docker build commands, whenever I update something in code and recompile, I have to copy my.zip in almost 20 folders. Is it possible we ADD the file from the root folder as

```
ADD ../my.zip /home/my.zip
```

Is it possible?

Comment: sure using `../` is fine, did you try?

Comment: Yes, I did but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Try building docker images from the parent directory with "-f" flag:

```
 docker build -t <your_tag> -f dirA/dirB/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: I already know this but I do not want to change my python script implementation. I want to Add ../my.zip file in image.